# Want distinct list of ids in mysql variable

Tags: mysql

```
Table
|id |user_id | req_user_id |
|---|--------|-------------|
|1  | 1      |   2         |
|2  | 2      |  9          | 
|3  | 7      |   2         |
```

When I search with user_id or req_user_id = 2 output should be **(1,9,7,2)**
tried

```
SET @list_req = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(user_id,',',req_user_id)) FROM send_request WHERE req_user_id= 2 or user_id=2);
```

output should be **(1,9,7,2)**

Comment: What happens with this code?

Comment: not getting distinct ids

Comment: `CONCAT(user_id,',',req_user_id)` will give 2 ids everytime. I would use a `union` and select the value you want, then group the result and aggregate it.

Comment: Something like `select group_concat(idyouwant) from (SELECT user_id as idyouwant FROM send_request WHERE req_user_id = 2 union all SELECT req_user_id as idyouwant FROM send_request WHERE user_id = 2) group by idyouwant` If you make sqlfiddle I could create real query.

Comment: how to group it into single variable for later use?

Comment: It's a query so do it as you had before.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select group_concat(id separator ',')
from (
  select user_id as id from t
  union 
  select req_user_id from t
) x
```

Result:

```
group_concat(id separator ',')
------------------------------
1,2,7,9
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I0rL0KHd).

Answer (score 0):

I see that @The Impaler's answer is great.

This is an other way to do it using `JSON_TABLE` and `JSON_OBJECTAGG` to extract distinct JSON array :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(user_id,',',req_user_id)) as ids
  FROM t 
  WHERE req_user_id= 2 or user_id=2
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_OBJECTAGG(item,''), '"|:| |\\{|\\}', '') as ids
FROM cte, JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('[', ids, ']'), '$[*]'
    COLUMNS(
        item TEXT PATH '$'
    )
) as items;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qcqpJw8g)